# Vue.js getElementById() targets wrong instance of component

Tags: vue.js, unique, instance, element

I am trying to build a little project in **Vue.js**, I have defined a child component which a parent component has six instances of.

The child component has a div element:

```
<div class="player" id="player1">
```

and a function which will change its own opacity:

```
changeOpacity(){document.getElementById('playerName').style.opacity = 0.5;}
```

The problem is when I tell the **second** instance of child component to execute its function, the **first** instance of child will change opacity.

My suspicion is it has something to do with unique div id's, that is by creating multiple instances of the child component the id: `playerName` is no longer unique.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how a child instance can access its own component elements without interfering with other instances of itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noted, this is because ids are global and `getElementById` will return the first element in the DOM with that id. It doesn't know anything about youe Vue component boundaries.

The correct way to access an element within a component is using `$refs`, not `getElementById`.

```html
<div ref="playerName">...</div>
```

```js
changeOpacity () {
  this.$refs.playerName.style.opacity = 0.5
}
```

However, directly manipulating the DOM isn't a very Vue way of doing this. Instead you should bind the opacity to a data property and change that.

```html
<div :style="{ opacity }">...</div>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```js
changeOpacity () {
  this.opacity = 0.5
}
```

In full:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      opacity: 1
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    changeOpacity () {
      this.opacity = 0.5
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div :style="{ opacity }">
    Content
  </div>
  <button @click="changeOpacity">Change</button>
</div>
```

If it's just a specific value for opacity, like 0.5, then you should really use a CSS class instead. That would look something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      halfHide: false
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    changeOpacity () {
      this.halfHide = true
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.half-hide {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div :class="{ 'half-hide': halfHide }">
    Content
  </div>
  <button @click="changeOpacity">Change</button>
</div>
```